# Sending and receiving data from an app over the internet

Tags: android, email, tcp, sms, communication

I recently created an app that sends and receives commands in the form of SMS text messages, being that sending a lot of text messages could become quite costly, i'm now looking for a new method to use to send and receive the data securely over the internet. Obviously one solution would be email, although I do not think this would be ideal due to emails stacking up and accounts etc. 
So basically, i'd like some advice on what my other options are....
How would sending a command using TCP work in android and how secure would it be? 
How would one go about setting up sending data over TCP?
Any feedback would be great, thanks

Comment: Sending data from an app over the internet should be free (user's data plan). You can use the networking features of the android phone to accomplish this. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html

Comment: Or, if you prefer telephony communication (which is usually less reliable than IP comm), you can checkout Asterisk open source PBX and hook it up to a VoIP provider for cheaper service. Not sure about it's SMS capabilities but the telephony aspect is great... I'm assuming it has SMS hook-in support.

Comment: -1 question too vague

Comment: Sorry if my question was too vague, i'll try and edit it to be more specific

Comment: @obitusis question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is [Google's Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) service. GCM is the standard way to push messages to/from the client. It requires several components to implement, however. One being a database to store GCM ids. Another is a back-end to do this.

It essentially works like this:

1. User downloads and installs and opens the application
2. Your application sends a request with your application's unique identifier to google for their GCM id (have to register on google's app center site)
3. Google responds to the device with their GCM id
4. Your application then sends (via network services or ajax in a webview) their GCM id to your server, which stores it for future use.

All of these components, however, are good things to have for growth and infrastructure support. Postgresql is a good, open-source relational database.

Other options:

1 - You could use websockets (https://github.com/koush/android-websockets)

Websockets, however, could considerably draw down the user's battery, extremely quickly if the app communicates even if it's not open, like... 'whooosh'

The benefits of using websockets is that it detaches your communication from Google.

Depending on your principals and/or beliefs, you may choose to go 100% independent by using soon-to-emerge web standards for detachment. Google (lol) "Extending the web to support personal network services" written by John Lyle, Claes Nilsson, Anders Isberg, and Shamal Faily. It's a good paper on the mobile communication debate.

Comment: Ah I see, is this similar to Apple's iMessage service? If so, I can see how this would be a good solution. You'll have to excuse my low level questions, i'm very new to Android development

Comment: Oh no worries, welcome aboard. You'll find it cheaper and more comfortable with less legal agreements ;) Yes, it's similar to the Apple Push Notification Service.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :) i'll do some research into implementing it into my application